# content - disposition header not working properly

Tags: java, image

I am building a small image scaling tool where the user first uploads an image to a webpage and on submitting that form it shows a scaled up image for saving . But the problem arises when the user sends a request for the same image to be scaled with different width and height parameters. In this case the content dispostion header that I have set in the servlet doesn't seem to work and the image after the second request is sent with the class name of the servlet only instead of the filename and extension I have mentioned in the content disposition header.

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;filename="+filename);
```

I also tried hardcoding it in the writer itself but the one that I am using doen't seem to have any parameter for filename

```
private void doDownload(HttpServletResponse resp, BufferedImage bump,
            InputStream filecontent) throws IOException {

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO
                .getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/jpeg");
        ImageWriter writer = iter.next();
        ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        iwp.setCompressionQuality(1);
        ImageOutputStream imgOut = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(out);
        writer.setOutput(imgOut);
        IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bump, null, null);
        writer.write(null, image, iwp);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        writer.dispose();

    }
```

Is there any way I can set the filename of the image while writing it to the outputstream?

Comment: *"shows a scaled up image"*  Why?

Comment: that's because I am writitng a image scaling program that provides high compression with higher quality images and lower sized images :P

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Static Integer variable in this Class.

```
private static int fileno=0;


private void doDownload(HttpServletResponse resp, BufferedImage bump,
            InputStream filecontent) throws IOException {

Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
iwp.setCompressionQuality(1);
String OUTPUTFILE = "C:/Users/Harish/Desktop/jpegFile"+fileno++;
File file = new File(OUTPUTFILE);
//Your fileName will be jpegFile0; and next time jpegFile1 and so on.
FileImageOutputStream imgOut = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
writer.setOutput(imgOut);
IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bump, null, null);
writer.write(null, image, iwp);
writer.dispose();

 }
```

Comment: thank you for answering but I am not writing it to hard drive location...cause I am directly writing it to the browser..actually I am retrieving the outputstream from the http response resp.getOutputStream()

Comment: appending the filename to the outputstream doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: I just gave you the idea (in saving it with a name). and why is it not working for you? any error?

Comment: when we create new File("C:\blah blah blah\j.jpeg") in this we can specify the file name but when i append resp.getOutputStream()+"j.jpg" it shows error "cannot convert from string to outputstream"