# Image changes color when saved with java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

When I save this image:

[image: Holiday Doodle]

with this method:

```
private final static Path ROOT_PATH = Paths.getPath("C:/images");

private static void saveImageFromWebSimple(final String url) {
    URL u = null;
    try {
        u = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String file = url.substring(url.indexOf("//") + 2);
    Path filePath = ROOT_PATH.resolve(file);
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(filePath.getParent());
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(u);
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", filePath.toFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is my result:

[image: Result]

This doesn't happen with all pictures though.

Can you tell me why?

Comment: 1) `ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", filePath.toFile());`  JPEG is not guaranteed to preserve the *exact* colors, but I think that goes beyond what it usually alters them.  2) If downloading it, just save it 'byte for byte' rather than using `ImageIO` (for either read *or* write).

Comment: If loading that image using `ImageIO` & displaying it directly (without any saving to disk involved), we can see the same result.  I've seen this before, but have forgotten the reason and therefore am having trouble finding for the answer..

Comment: Seems so. I've done a research before asking this Q but have not found that. I linked to this Q from the original to get more attention because it's not really closed imho.

Comment: *"it's not really imho."*  It's not really what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to @uckelman's [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors#comment21166430_9395544) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors), Java's decoder makes a different assumption about the format of the image than most other renders when the image is missing the JFIF header:

> I believe the answer to your question of how to detect the bad JPEGs
> is found [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4712797) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676701/java-jpeg-converter-for-odd-image-types). What you have is a JPEG with no JFIF marker.
> All other image loaders assume that the data is YCbCr in that case,
> except for ImageIO, which assumes that it is RGB when channels 1 and 2
> are not subsampled. So, check whether the first 4 bytes are FF D8 FF
> E1, and if so, whether channels 1 and 2 are subsampled. That's the
> case where you need to convert.

Comment: Thanks antiduh but PLEASE vote up @uckleman 's comment as well!

Comment: I added this to the other answer, but in case somebody stumbles across it here:

I was running into this issue, and I actually found a third party library that handled this for me. https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Literally all I had to do was include this in my maven dependencies and the jpegs that were coming out in weird colors started getting read in normally. I didn't even have to change a line of code.

Comment: I'd heartily second @JamesFiala's comment - after reading that I gave it a go in my Clojure project and it fixed my issue a treat. A very straightforward solution.  Thanks James!